# Why am i getting the wrong output? (Python random number generator calculator)

Tags: python, calculator

This program is suppose to generate two random numbers and have the user input the result.  If the user input is correct, then the program will print 'You are correct!'  If wrong, the program will print 'You are wrong!'  However, when the user's answer is correct, the program still outputs "You are wrong!' Not sure why

```
 import random
 first = random.randint(0,9) 
 second = random.randint(0,9) 
 result = first + second
 answer = input(str(first) + ' + ' + str(second) + ': ')

 if result == answer:
     print('You are correct!')
 else:
     print('Sorry you are wrong!')
```

Comment: If you're using Python 3.x, then `input(...)` returns a string... so you need to convert the result to an integer to successfully compare against `result` first.

Comment: Just correct the if: `if result == int(answer):`

Comment: Thank You! your solution worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `result` is an integer and the `answer` is a string.

You need to convert the result to a string before comparing:

```py
if str(result) == answer:
```

Comment: This won't always work.

Comment: Could you give an example when it doesn't? The spaces?

Comment: Sure: first=4 second=5 result=9, answer = "        9". Output is: 'Sorry you are wrong!'

Comment: Okay, then `if result == int(answer):` will fail when the answer is 'nine' ;) The question was not about data validation so I didn't use `if str(result) == answer.strip()`

Comment: If answer='nine', then neither way will work. Why would the user enter 'nine' when asked '4 + 5:'.  Also, the answers in the duplicate question usually involve `int()` somewhere.

Comment: My point is that the `int()` version will crash while the `str()` version will say about the wrong answer ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200660/discussion-between-quamrana-and-ababak).